# Error ing *ngFor loop in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, ngfor

I want to render some data in loop:

```
  <div *ngFor="let data of parameters.items.tableConfig.nodes">
    <table-item [data]=data></table-item>
  </div>
```

But data

And I have error:

> ```
> EXCEPTION: Error in ./TableWidgetComponent class TableWidgetComponent - inline template:7:17 caused by: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined
> ```

How I can wait before data come, and then render view?

`*ngIf="parameters && parameters.items.tableConfig.nodes`" does not helps me.

Comment: `parameters.items` property `tableConfig` is undefined

Comment: Provide some more information e.g. interface for parameters model. Are we accessing parameters asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
<div *ngFor="let data of parameters?.items?.tableConfig?.nodes">
    <table-item [data]=data></table-item>
  </div>
```

by using elevis operator `(?)` [also called `safe navigation operator`] it will prevent angular to throw error , beneficial in case where data is coming asynchronously like in your case

Here is detailed information about this

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator

Comment: Cool. It works.
But can you share with me link with full explanation of this.

Comment: check my Update with link @MaxKarpovets

Answer (score 1):

Given you say 'How I can wait before data come,..', I take the data comes from an asynchronous call. So either an Observable or a Promise. You have a number of options here;

Add an if-condition around the actual loop.

`<div *ngIf="parameters.items.tableConfig">...</div>`

Use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) (?.) to guard against `undefined` and `null`.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of parameters.items.tableConfig?.nodes">
   <table-item [data]=data></table-item>
</div>
```

Use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html).

It accepts a Promise or Observable and updates the view with the response data when the Promise is resolved or when the Observable emits a new value.

```
export class MyComponent {
   nodePromise: Promise<Node>; // e.g. with Promise.
}

<div *ngFor="let data of nodePromise | async">
   <table-item [data]=data></table-item>
</div>
```